# Spring themed cryptic clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

In the hope that the weather will finally become spring-like where I live, the next set of themed cryptic clues will be spring themed.

Heard kissable flowers (6)

Head loses its head for water (4)

Songbird's prank (4)

Point hesitant to become a holiday (6)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heard kissable flowers (6)

> TULIPS - "flowers", sounds like "two lips"

Head loses its head for water (4)

> RAIN - "water", BRAIN (head) without the first letter

Songbird's prank (4)

> LARK - double definition

Point hesitant to become a holiday (6)

> EASTER - "holiday", EAST (point) + ER (a hesitation in speech)

Answer (score 3):

## Partial Answer

Clue 1

> Tulips
>  Homonym for "two lips", hence kissable

Clue 2
Don't know

Clue 3

> Lark
>  A lark is a songbird and also means prank

Clue 4

> Easter
>  East is a point of the compass and "er" is a hesitation word giving the holiday Easter

Comment: 1 and 4 are correct. 3 is not, unless it's a typo.

Comment: good work. Upvote, but Zandar got it first so I accepted him.